# wp_list_categories: get latest featured_image of category

Tags: loop, categories

I was thinking about a nicer way to display the categories in my sidebar.
Instead of a plain list style, I'd like to have images / thumbnails show up as well.

Currently I'm using the following:

```
<?php wp_list_categories('show_last_updated=1&show_count=1&title_li='); ?>
```

Simply displaying the name/link + post count of each category.
I want to keep, that but also add a thumbnail to it.

I've been browsing through this board for answers and also thought about how to do it, but I couldn't find a solution yet.

I guess I have to create a function that gets the featured image of the latest post in that category. If a post has more categories, that also shouldn't cause any problems.

Creating a loop with only 1 post in that category and only outputting the thumbnail would be an option, but to set it so that the thumbnail and category match could be a hassle.
I'm sure that there must be a better way to do it.

I'm not looking for a plugin (as I'm sure there are some), I want to hardcode it.

If anybody has a good idea or some advice how to approach this, then please help me out.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom [Walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/Walker_Class), the easiest of which in your case is the `Walker_Category` and extend it like so:

```
class CategoryThumbnail_Walker extends Walker_Category {
    // A new element has been stumbled upon and has ended
    function end_el( &$output, $category, $depth, $args ) {
        // Output the standard link ending
        parent::end_el( &$output, $category, $depth, $args );

        // Get one post
        $posts = get_posts( array(
            // ...from this category
            'category' => $category->cat_ID,
            'numberposts' => 1
        ) );
        // If a post has been found
        if ( isset($posts[0]) ) {
            // Get its thumbnail and append it to the output
            $featured = get_the_post_thumbnail( $posts[0]->ID, 'thumbnail', null );
            $output .= $featured;
        }
    }
}
```

Now your `wp_list_categories` can utilize that walker by supplying an additional `walker` argument like so:

```
wp_list_categories( array('walker' => new CategoryThumbnail_Walker()) );
```

As you can see we have two additional queries for each category, one to get the latest post, and one to get its featured image, so make sure that this overhead is acknowledged.

If you want to further customize the output you will have to override all of the functionality of `end_el` or `start_el` for the `Walker_Category` class.

### Duplicates

To make sure that no duplicate images are shown you have to do the following things:

- store the displayed image in an array
- check with every new image whether it exists in the array
- if it exists - get next post and check its image
- if it does not exist, add it to array and output
- understand what you're doing, how it will work and how to turn in into working code in your context (by reading the docs and learning more about PHP and WordPress)

So the code would look something like this:

```
class CategoryThumbnail_Walker extends Walker_Category {

    // A new element has been stumbled upon and has ended
    function end_el( &$output, $category, $depth, $args ) {
        // Output the standard link ending
        parent::end_el( &$output, $category, $depth, $args );

        // Get one post
        $posts = get_posts( array(
            // ...from this category
            'category' => $category->cat_ID,
            'numberposts' => 10
        ) );

        // we'll record the seen images here
        if ( !isset($this->images_seen) ) $this->images_seen = array();

        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            // Get its thumbnail and append it to the output
            $featured = get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'thumbnail', null );
            // have we already seen this image?
            if ( in_array($featured, $this->images_seen) ) continue;
            else {
                $this->images_seen []= $featured;
                $output .= $featured;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. It doesn't output anything, though. I put the code snippet above into my function.php and changed the function calling to     `<?php wp_list_categories( array('walker' => new CategoryThumbnail_Walker()) ); ?>` The only thing that changed is that there's now a headline saying "Categories" above the category list.

Comment: Do you have posts in your categories? Does the latest one have a featured image? The code above has been tested and works for me. Let's figure out why it doesn't for you.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue(no thumb).Thanks! If I wanted to style the whole thing a bit, would I have to do that within the function? Like for example I'd like to get rid of the "Categories" title that it's displaying right now, because now it's double. Also, is it possible to write the function so that it will never pick the same image at all? E.g. if one post has 3 categories, then in the list it will display the same image 3 times. Instead it could get the featured image of the post before that recent post in order to avoid a double image. Or is that too complicated?

Comment: Currently it looks like this: http://i53.tinypic.com/20syfqe.jpg [live] (http://www.zoomingjapan.com/blog/)

Comment: Please take a look at the [`wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) documentation, esp. at the `title_li` argument; when you replaced your function call by mine didn't you see that your `title_li` is removed now? Please read the documentation. To further customize you will have to implement all of the functionality of the `Walker_Category` class (http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/category-template.php#L773) and extend the `Walker` class instead, that way you'll be able to control the output exactly.

Comment: I order to get rid of duplicates you have to keep track of what's images have already been pulled in and if an image is duplicate, fetch the next post image (for that make sure `numberposts` is more than 1, so that the array of posts is large enough to choose featured images from. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much. The code for the dublicates doesn't work unfortunately. Now, it only displays one thumbnail for the top category (which isn't even the one of the latest post in that category), the other categories suddenly don't get an image anymore. Also, what is quite important to me is that the thumbnail is a link to the respective category as well. How would I have to modify the code in order to achieve that? I had a look at the documentaiton, but this looks quite difficult. Also, can I merge my previous function call with the walker? If so, how would that look?

Comment: The code works for me, I may have edited something after you copy-pasta'd it. Try again and switch errors on to be more specific where it does not work. In order to provide a walker your arguments for the `wp_list_categories()` function have to be an array as opposed to being a string, so convert it into an array. `$arg['title_li'] = ''; $arg['walker'] = new ...; $arg['showcount'] = true;` etc. Just some friendly advice, japanworm, 38 questions vs. 3 answers is not good karma; either you start reading the docs, answer questions, or you may soon find lack of quality answers to your questions.

Comment: Also, after reading about it here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail I tried it, as I want to change the thumb size, but it doesn't take effect: `            $featured = get_the_post_thumbnail( $posts[0]->ID, array(244,65), 'thumbnail', null );`

Comment: Turn on error reporting, the function call is not correct. The function accepts 3 arguments, you're giving it four.

Comment: Thanks so much, the edited code worked well. I'm thankful for your advice. I'm really trying hard, but I'm a complete beginner, so I'm still struggling - and I don't have the money to hire a freelancer. Sorry :( So, I'm really, really thankful for the help I get here form people who know much more than I currently do.

Comment: How would I turn on error reporting? Sorry, this is the first time I hear of it!

Comment: `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in *wp-config.php* + http://www.phpreferencebook.com/tips/display-all-php-errors-and-warnings/

Comment: I got the thumbnail size issue to work. Was quite easy in the end. Also, I read through all your comments one more time. So, if I understood correctly I am supposed to implement the title_li into the walker instead of the function call? Thanks for the link, I'm gonna put this into my wp-config.php :)

Comment: No, instead of calling `wp_list_categories('show_last_updated=1&show_count=1&title_li=');` you do this http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=HeUXA0vN, WordPress accepts arguments both as a query and as an array.

Comment: I already tried something similar, but had a syntax error, so thank you very much for the code snippet as it worked great. I'm pretty much done now. I'm trying to figure out how to make the thumbnail into a link for the category, but I already think I saw how to do it somehwere. Gonna try it out now :)

Comment: `$output .= '<a href="...">'.$featured.'</a>'`

Comment: Thanks so much! I really feel stupid:  `$output .= '<a href="<?php get_category_link( $category_id ); ?>" title="Category Name">'.$featured.'</a>';`  I guess I need to look for another way to get the category_link as this doesnt work (as it outputs http://website/php-code). Really, you helped me so much, thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: `$output .= '<a href="http://www.zoomingjapan.com/category/'.get_the_category().'" title="Category Name">'.$featured.'</a>';
                break;` With this I feel that I'm already very close. However this is outputting `http://.../category/Array`

Comment: Learn how to use `var_dump($variable)` to see what variables contain (esp. Arrays and Objects) and pick the information you need.  `$category->cat_name` or `$category['cat_name']` is what you're looking for. So `$category = get_the_category()` and off you go.

Comment: I will have a look at it, thanks. Hopefully that will help me in the future to get things done a bit quicker :) I'm not sure if I understood it correctly. What I tried: `$category = get_the_category();
  $output .= '<a href="http://www.zoomingjapan.com/category/'.$category->cat_name.'" title="Category Name">'.$featured.'</a>';` which outputs as "http://../category/", so the category name doesn't appear.

Comment: Way too many comments, people (system flagged it as issue). If you need this much discussion it's best to get yourself separate room in chat and do it there.

Comment: Is it possible to modify this to work with custom taxonomies? I'm confused about it.

Answer (score 2):

I know you said you wanted to not use a plugin, but I am still going to recommend this: [Taxonomy Images](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-images/)

You can always just hardcode it into your functions file.
It adds a nice little interface to the categories for adding a specific images to each category, and supplies some easy ways to get that image on your pages. It also works on custom taxonomies with no problem.

I mention the plugin because, for a project I was working on I was trying your first approach (to just show the featured image of the latest post in that category) but when a particular post was in more than one category, the same image was repeated multiple times and looked funky.

Having an image for each category kept a  consistent look. The plugin is easy to use so the client could change the image with no probleem. I also wrote a little if statement in case the client created a new category but failed to add an image so that it then went on to use the thumbnail of the latest post for that category (sort of long-winded but you get the point):

```
 <?php
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <!--thumbnail -->
<? /*asks if the category has an image...else use the post Thumbnail...then  if not use the wedding.jpg  */ ?>
<span  class="lighten"><a href="<?= add_query_arg('t', strtolower($term->name), home_url( '/videos/' )); ?>">

    <?php 
    $image_link =  "<a href=".home_url( '/' ).(strtolower($term->name)).">";
    $image = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-list-the-terms', '', array(
        'taxonomy'     => 'video_types',
        'image_size' => 'detail',
        'after'        => '',
        'after_image'  => '',
        'before'       => '',
        'before_image' => ''
         )
    );


    if ( ! empty( $image ) ) {print $image;}

            elseif ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {the_post_thumbnail(); } 
             else { ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/weddings.jpg" alt="<?php echo $term->name;?>" />
    <?php } ?></a></span><!--#lighten -->
        </div><!--#thumb -->
           <?php
          endwhile;
          ?>
      <?php
        }
      }
    }
    wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm sure other people with appreciate your answer and I'll save it for future reference, but for now I'm trying to go without plugins as often as possible :)

Comment: Here's a currently maintained plugin that also assigns image to category https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-custom-taxonomy-image/

Comment: another approach is to create a category field with Advanced Custom Fields and pull in image into a custom category walker like: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/170603/48604