# Add Thumbnail to wp_list_categories()

Tags: taxonomy, thumbnails, walker, categories

I'm using the following code to display a list of my taxonomy terms in my home page:

```
$customPostTaxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( 'guide' );

if( count( $customPostTaxonomies ) > 0 )
{
    foreach( $customPostTaxonomies as $tax )
    {
        $args = array(
            'orderby'       => 'name',
            'show_count'    => 0,
            'pad_counts'    => 0,
            'hierarchical'  => 1,
            'taxonomy'      => $tax,
        );

        wp_list_categories( $args );
    }
}
```

Now i'm trying to add to the title, the term thumbnail that i had setup with a custom field to this list ( that i can output with the following code ):

```
$saved_data = get_tax_meta( $term_id, 'image_field_id', true );
echo '<img src="' . $saved_data['src'] . '">';
```

I really don't know how to mix them together... I've read about custom walker class but I don't know how to use it. Can anybody show me an example of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The original question uses `get_tax_meta()` which does not exist in WordPress core but may be a custom function created by the asker. In this case we could switch it out just as well with [`get_term_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/).

You could try this:

```
class List_Category_Images extends Walker_Category {
    function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $saved_data = get_tax_meta( $category->term_id, 'image_field_id', true );

        $cat_name = apply_filters(
            'list_cats',
            esc_attr( $category->name ),
            $category
        );

        $link = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $category ) ) . '" ';
        if ( $args['use_desc_for_title'] && ! empty( $category->description ) ) {
            $link .= 'title="' . esc_attr( strip_tags( apply_filters( 'category_description', $category->description, $category ) ) ) . '"';
        }

        $link .= '>';
        $link .= '<img src="' . $saved_data['src'] . '">';
        $link .= $cat_name . '</a>';

        if ( ! empty( $args['show_count'] ) ) {
            $link .= ' (' . number_format_i18n( $category->count ) . ')';
        }
        if ( 'list' == $args['style'] ) {
            $output .= "\t<li";
            $class = 'cat-item cat-item-' . $category->term_id;
            if ( ! empty( $args['current_category'] ) ) {
                $_current_category = get_term( $args['current_category'], $category->taxonomy );
                if ( $category->term_id == $args['current_category'] ) {
                    $class .=  ' current-cat';
                } elseif ( $category->term_id == $_current_category->parent ) {
                    $class .=  ' current-cat-parent';
                }
            }
            $output .=  ' class="' . $class . '"';
            $output .= ">$link\n";
        } else {
            $output .= "\t$link<br />\n";
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm doing is modifying one of the methods inside the [Walker_Category class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_category/) which in this case the function is actually creating the link to the term / category. At the top of the method I call the `get_tax_meta()` function ( which I assume works, as this is not built into WordPress ). Then I add the image directly before the name of the category:

```
$link .= '>';
$link .= '<img src="' . $saved_data['src'] . '">';
$link .= $cat_name . '</a>';
```

Now all you need to do is define a new instance of this class in your `wp_list_categories()` function:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'       => 'name',
    'show_count'    => 0,
    'pad_counts'    => 0,
    'hierarchical'  => 1,
    'taxonomy'      => $tax,
    'walker'        => new List_Category_Images
);
wp_list_categories( $args );
```

Comment: As the source of `get_tax_meta` is unknown, then replacing `$saved_data` with `$image = get_field('thumb', $category);` on line 3  (and by implication line 13) where 'thumb' is the custom field name, returned as URL, does the trick

Comment: Note that `get_field()` is only available in the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. I used `get_tax_meta()` as that what OP used in their question. In other snippets this should be replaced with `get_term_meta()`